# Updating RDS Engine Version (Minor) via cloudformation - Immediate or during next window?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

Currently using AWS RDS PostgreSQL 10.6 and would like to upgrade to 10.9.
We're using Cloudformation templates, and I would like to schedule the upgrade to the next maintenance window, instead of immediately.

From the [RDS FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/):

> By default, the upgrade will be applied or during your next maintenance window. You can also choose to upgrade immediately by selecting the Apply Immediately option in the console API.

From this I understand that by default, changes will applied to your next maintenance window unless specified to apply immediately.

That said - If I update my RDS Cloudformation template, will it apply immediately or during the maintenance window? Is there a way to specify it to update during the maintenance window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely try this in your dev environment before doing it in production.
Updating EngineVersion through CloudFormation does currently NOT work like the console. If I recall correctly, CloudFormation will **replace** your existing instance.

Comment: Yes, in hindsight it was a silly question. Tried it in our test database and can confirm that changes were applied immediately. Thanks!

Comment: CloudFormation is smart enough to upgrade in place, rather than replacing. But yes, it's immediate.

Comment: @ThrawnCA your comment is contradictory with the answer . why was the answer accepted. I am confused now

Comment: That comment is wrong, it will not do an upgrade. Please see this suggested improvement: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/216

Comment: By "upgrade in place" I meant that you don't lose data; it doesn't create a new blank instance.

Comment: Yes it does, that's exactly what happens if you do it in cloud formation. Upgrading through the console or using the cli will do an upgrade in place though.

Comment: It looks like the replacement/upgrade behavior is not the same depending on whether you are changing the `EngineVersion` on a [AWS::RDS::DBCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-engineversion) (requires replacement) or a [AWS::RDS::DBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-engineversion) (requires "some interruption"). Check the related AWS documentation pages for more informations.

Comment: @MaximeRossini No, the documentation for both cluster and instance says "Some interruptions" on updating EngineVersion.

Comment: @ThrawnCA You are right, but the documentation (and probably the AWS API) was updated since my answer was posted: [AWS::RDS::DBCluster](http://web.archive.org/web/20200502095106if_/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-engineversion) (may 2020 version).